# Joomla Background Image?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, background-image, joomla1.7

I'm sure there is a very simple explanation for this but...  How do I add a background image to my Joomla site?  I am using a modified version of Atomic.  The obvious thing to do would be to simply go into the template.css file and add a background-image property to my body or divs... however, it doesn't take.  If I change the background color however that works fine.  Perhaps the path is incorrect but I've tried it a hundred times and I doubt I'd get the path wrong every time.  I've even tried placing the image file in the root folder, thus eliminating the possible mistyped path to the file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to open the image in your browser and, if that works, try to display the image in your layout not as background but as a normal foreground image on. If that works too, you have a problem with your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the template CSS file is definitely the way to do it. This should help -

Folder to put image in:

```
JOOMLA FOLDER/templates/atomic/images
```

CSS to use:

```
#ID.class{background:URL(../images/background.png);}
```

If that doesn't work, post a link so we can debug for you.